# Datatable.js search bar missing when data display using php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, searchbar

I am displaying records from mysql database but every time it loads data the table messing up, the sorting function on the header of the table missing, and the search bar on the top went missing.

I've tried to put plain HTML text to every field and it works. I really don't know why it doesn't php codes doesn't work.

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">TEACHER LIST</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="teacher-record" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>School Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach ( $teacher as $user ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i+= 1; ?></td>
                        <td><?php 
                            //Displays School Name
                            global $wpdb;
                            $teacher_email = $user->user_email;
                            echo display($teacher_email,4)
                        ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo esc_html( $user->first_name ) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo esc_html( $user->last_name ) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo display($teacher_email,6) ?></td> -->
                        <td><?php echo esc_html( $user->user_email ) ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-view-shelf" data-id="<?php echo esc_html( $user->ID ); ?>">View</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-update-shelf" data-id="<?php echo esc_html( $user->ID ); ?>">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete-shelf" data-id="<?php echo esc_html( $user->ID ); ?>" data-email="<?php echo esc_html( $user->user_email ); ?>">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>School Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```